# XML-XSD: How to define namespaces correctly?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am wondering how to define a namespace correctly with XML and XSD. I have the following XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:app="ms.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="ms.xsd">
    <app:contactPerson>
        <app:name>Florian</app:name>
        <app:countryCode>FR</app:countryCode>
    </app:contactPerson>
    <app:contactPerson>
        <app:name>Gabi</app:name>
        <app:countryCode>DE,EE,EL,FI,FR,IE,UK</app:countryCode>
    </app:contactPerson>
    <app:contactPerson>
        <app:name>Gert</app:name>
        <app:countryCode>GB</app:countryCode>
    </app:contactPerson>
    <app:origin/>
</application>
```

And the schema is defined by the file *ms.xsd* in the same folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    version="0.2"
    targetNamespace="ms.xsd"
    xmlns:app="ms.xsd">
    <xs:element name="application" type="app:applicationType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="applicationType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="contactPerson" type="app:contactPersonType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="origin" type="app:originType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="contactPersonType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="countryCode" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="originType">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="further_details" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I already tried a lot of things. The error I get with this (currently) final version is

**ERROR: Element 'application': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.**

Is this because the xsd-reference in the xml-file is within the application-tag, such that it comes 'too late'? When I add an "envelope"-tag around everything and put the xsd-definition there, I get the message

**ERROR: Element 'envelope': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.**

So now I'm really confused on how to do this correctly. I am validating the XML against the XSD using XML-Tools in Notepadd++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try app:application ...
This should work. No matter that the declaration comes after.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to add a default namespace:

```
xmlns="ms.xsd"
```

This will put the `<application>` into that namespace. Actually, you could then omit all the other `app:` prefixes if you wanted to.  Though I think @jmcollin92's solution is better - just filling in the gaps.

BTW: Your `xsi:schemaLocation` should be:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="ms.xsd ms.xsd"
```

The first `ms.xsd` is the namespace (which can be any arbitrary string); the second `ms.xsd` is the file where the schema can be found (an URI - usually a file or URL) - actually, it can be a list of such pairs.  Strictly speaking, your xml tools should have flagged an  error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought of a default namespace, but the XML is delivered and can't be changed. I am just building the XSD file for it.

Comment: Your hint with the `xsi:schemaLocation` is very much appreciated.